# Can't use azure servicebusservice with python

Tags: python

When I call the execute the following code i get a "No module named request" fail. I have downloaded and installed the azure-sdk-for-python from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/v0.11.0

my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Code for measuring pressure from an Emerson pressuretransducer. 
#The transducer outputs 4-20 mA through a resistor of 200 Ohms.
from ABE_ADCPi import ADCPi
from ABE_helpers import ABEHelpers
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
import time
import os
import json


#To use shared access signature authentication, the service bus service has been created.
sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace=***, shared_access_key_name=***, shared_access_key_value=***)

#The setup of the ADCPi.
i2c_helper = ABEHelpers()
bus = i2c_helper.get_smbus()
adc = ADCPi(bus, 0x68, 0x69, 16)
adc.set_pga(1)

#Declaration of variables.
offsetVoltage = 0.8
barPrmA = 0.625
mAtoVoltVoltage = 0.2

while True:
  #The convertion has been initiated from channel 1, returns voltage.
  voltage = adc.read_voltage(1)
  #print voltage

  #The measured voltage converted into Bar.
  Bar = ((voltage-offsetVoltage)/mAtoVoltVoltage)*barPrmA


  #Bar to kPa.
  kPa = Bar*100
  #The data and device number is written with json encoding.
  data = {'DeviceId':1 , 'Tryk': str(kPa)}

  #The pressure is pushed to the database.
  sbs.send_event('mrceventhub2323', json.dumps(data))


  time.sleep(1)
```

When i execute this code. It exits with this fail message:

```
python PressureAzure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PressureAzure.py", line 6, in <module>
    from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .servicebusservice import ServiceBusService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 19, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

anyone around here who can help me out?
I'm wondering if I need to install this module called requests ? or should it have been in installed with azure?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Nevermind this question. I fixed the problem by downloading and installing the module called requests in python. Use the command as follows (you have to have python-pip installed as well):

```
sudo pip install requests
```

This fixed my problem.